# Document not open in Browser

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, document-library, owa

There is SharePoint 2013 foundation server and it is beings used for DMS. OOB library with folders are user to save the documents.

I have selected the **Open document in Browser** , but on clicking the document it is getting download.

As per my knowledge, to view only the document we don't need to OWA server ! Is it right of do I need to setup a OWA server to open the document as well !

Answer (score 0):

You need to have web apps enabled to view the documents in browser. If you have webapps, you can even edit the document in the browser.

Comment: where I can find this web apps !